# Error: "expected primary-expression before int"

Tags: c++

I am getting an error: expected primary-expression before `int` when I try to return a 2 values in bool function, I think its a member function error.

```
bool binaryTreeTraversal::LeafNode(int node)
{
        return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(int node) == NULL &&   
        binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(int node) == NULL);

}

class binaryTreeTraversal

{
public:
    int TreeNodes[2^5];
    int size;
    binaryTreeTraversal(void);
    bool LeafNode(int node);
    int RootNode(int node);
    int LeftPtr(int node);
    int RightPtr(int node);
    int length();
    int preOrderTraversal(int);
    int inOrderTraversal(int);
    int postOrderTraversal(int);
};

bool binaryTreeTraversal::LeafNode(int node)
{
    return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node) == NULL &&
            binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(node) == NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Making this question useful to others: "expected primary-expression" means "I thought you were going to put an expression here."

An expression is an object, a function call, or operators applied to objects and function calls . For example, `x + f(y)` is an expression involving variables `x` and `y`, the function `f` and the operator `+`.

There are many types of expressions, but the distinction isn't important for the purpose of this error message.

After the open-parenthesis denoting a function call, you are expected to enter an expression, representing the value to pass as a parameter to the function call. But instead, the compiler saw the word `int`, which is not a variable or a function or an operator.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(int node) == NULL &&
        binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(int node) == NULL);
```

to:

```
return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node) == NULL &&
        binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(node) == NULL);
```

EDIT:

The return type from `LeftPtr()` and `RightPtr()` is `int`:

```
class binaryTreeTraversal
{
public:
    ...
    bool LeafNode(int node)
    {
        return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node) == 0 &&
                binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(node) == 0);
    }
};
```

or:

```
class binaryTreeTraversal
{
public:
    ...
    bool LeafNode(int node)
    {
        return (!binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node) &&
                !binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(node));
    }
};
```

or as `LeftPtr()` and `RightPtr()` are not `virtual`:

```
class binaryTreeTraversal
{
public:
    ...
    bool LeafNode(int node)
    {
        return (!LeftPtr(node) && !RightPtr(node));
    }
};
```

Comment: i am getting a warning: NULL used in arithmetic
if i take off the 'int'

Comment: What is the return type of `binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr()`? I am guessing it is not a pointer.

Comment: at that point you mentioned, it(binaryTreeTraversal) is a constructor.

Comment: It is not a constructor call: `binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr()` is just using a fully qualified call to a member function of `binaryTreeTraversal`. What is return type from `LeftPtr()` and `RightPtr()`?

Comment: binaryTreeTraversal is a class
binaryTreeTraversal(void) is a constructor
and i need to cut the tree nodes, when it reaches the leaf node, so that i need the part there.

Comment: you will be right at that point, but what is exact problem with mine, i just created a constructor and with that constructor i separately write a function call, does it make any change with your part of code

Answer (score 2):

This is just a simple mistake so you don't need to worry ;-)
//wrong code

```
1: int displayMessage (int num1, int num2)
2: {
3:   displayMessage(int num1, int num2);
4: }
```

Line #3, you have written (int num1, int num2), Both the variables are defined already so you don't need to define again.

```
Please don't try to define the variables again. 




 1: int displayMessage (int num1, int num2)enter code here
    2: {
    3:   displayMessage(num1,num2);
    4: }
```

You can go through this for the basic understanding [enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-definition-and-declaration/)

Answer (score 1):

return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(**int node**) == NULL &&
    binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(**int node**) == NULL);

//remove int from bolded part

Comment: it shows a warning: NULL used in arithmetic, when i remove and build it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(int node) == NULL && binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(int node) == NULL);
```

should be

```
return (binaryTreeTraversal::LeftPtr(node) == NULL && binaryTreeTraversal::RightPtr(node) == NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool binaryTreeTraversal::LeafNode(int node)
{
    return ((LeftPtr(node) == NULL) && (RightPtr(node) == NULL));
}
```